# DataTypeAttribute overrides class element set in EditorTemplate String.chtml

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to set the ViewData["class"] of my String.chtml EditorTemplate. It's working when I remove the DataType.x attribute from my ViewModel. But I want to keep my DataType.Password and apply additional css classes.

I'm using:

1. Bootstrapper 3.3.1
2. ASP.NET MVC 5.2

I've tried:

1. Disabling JavaScript.
2. Settings the style with TextBoxFor instead of TextBox in String.chtml.

I would prefer:

1. Not to add extra CSS unless necessary (because of Bootstrapper).
2. Not use JavaScript / JQuery to fix the issue.
3. Use ASP.NET MVC to solve to conflict.

**This is my String.chtml in the EditorTemplates folder:**
[image: EditorTemplate String.chtml]

**The view model (with the DataTypeAttributes that mess up my EditorTemplate):**
[image]

**And this is the Login.chtml that uses the new EditorTemplate (String.chtml):**
[image]

**My current result:**
[image]

How do I add a CSS class to Html.ForEditor when DataType.Password / DataType.EmailAddress attribute is specified?

Let me know when something is unclear and I'll add/change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is a fundamental misunderstanding of what's actually going on.  The DataType is not overriding your ViewData, it's causing a totally different template to be selected.. ie.. the built-n default Password or EmailAddress templates.

The purpose of DataType is to select a template for rendering.  So what you actually want to do is create a EmailAddress.cshtml and a Password.cshtml template and add the form-control attributes to those.  However, those are not really necessary since you can add these attributes to the EditorFor in MVC 5.1 or greater.

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Spot on. Searched for hours ;). Creating the EmailAddress.chtml and Password.chtml fixed the issue.

Comment: @Measuring - I personally prefer not to mess with the default templates if I don't have to, even if it means specifying the attributes in each helper call.. but to each their own.